# Rails5, unpermitted params in nested form, while associating existing objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms, strong-parameters, fields-for

Why why why...?

Three models (**FirstModel**, **SecondModel**, **JoinedModel**), JoinedModel belongs to both others and other two `has_many` of each other, through **JoinedModel**. 
JoinedModel `accepts_nested_attributes_for` first_model and second_model.

It also validates presence of `first_model_id` and `second_model_id`.

Joined model strong params:

```
private
 def joined_params
   params.require(:joined_model).permit(:first_model_id, :second_model_id,
                  :first_models_attributes => [:id, :name],
                  :second_models_attributes => [:id, :full_name])
 end
```

JoinedModel's _form:

```
<%= form_for(joined_model) do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :second_models do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.select(SecondModel.all.map {|c| [ c.full_name, c.id ] }, { include_blank: true }) -%>
```

(and the same `f.fields_for` for FirstModel)

When I submit this form, I get

> Unpermitted params first_models, second_models

And query:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"gvW/OrOXJruAK0ZD+uoajJ4N+dZvpmZF8Ay0TOKF9HPO19d4tRBoWz0C4VoaOABYat8KzrryL8lp5ax+Y9ZJRg==",
>   "joined_model"=>{"first_models"=>{"first_model_id"=>"1"},
>   "second_models"=>{"second_model_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Create Joined
>   model"}

I dont know why, how etc. form tries to send a hash - `"second_models"=>{"second_model_id"=>"1"}` it supposed to be just like `"second_model_id"=>"1"` and it does like this if my form uses simple `f.number_field :first_model_id` instead of `select`...

Comment: You should add an answer with your answer, then accept it. Feels weird, but is absolutely acceptable (and encouraged)! Also, maybe think about a title with more clarity? How can we help others find this solution when they have this problem?

Comment: yes, good idea, i will post it. About the title, I thought its even better like this - many relevant keywords (could't think any others :))) )

Comment: Your title should be a concise, relevant question or problem statement. Search works plenty well without keyword loading. ;)

Comment: Hm, maybe yes, time has come when machines became smarter... I will fix it :) thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and will leave this post, since many similar unanswered questions found on StackOverflow

So, the answer was to use parent's fields builder for `select`, like:

```
<%= form_for(joined_model) do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :second_models do |ff| %>
  <%= f.select(SecondModel.all.map {|c| [ c.full_name, c.id ] }, { include_blank: true }) -%>
```

Looks like it works all fine now, but if anyone knows why I even need to provide builder object (in my case `|ff|`) for nested fields if I am not even using it, I will give a Hi Five and a Tango dance!

**UPDATE:**

So I found that in this situation I didn't even needed `fields_for`... Now it all makes sence, since here I was creating a new JoinedModel's record and only **selecting** other two (existing) records and association simply lets me grab those methods... Bit lame, but oh well...